# Formulating Date in Excel 2013

Tags: excel, date, excel-2013

I am using MS Office Excel 2013 in English, I have the following question.

I used this formula `"=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(D5),ISTEXT(D5)),TODAY(),"not posted")"` to place todays date in `C5`, when I enter text or a number in `D5`, but I get a number in the returned value, instead of the actual date.

What is incorrect in the formula? explicitly: I enter "yes" in `D5` I get "42621" in `C5` instead of the current date.

Comment: Please add a tag indicating what language and/or tool you're using.

Comment: I am using the English version of MS Office Excel 2013 if that is what you are asking.

Comment: That information needs to be in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the cursor to the intended cell and press `ALT + H + N + Short Date`. This should do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing incorrect in the formula. 42621 is the numeric representation of today's date. Just give cell C5 a Date-type format.